# Using Reactstrap and/or availity-reactstrap-validation with an AvField is it possible to display the green "valid" box when a valid item is entered?

Tags: reactjs, validation, reactstrap

Right now, using this:

```
                        <AvField name="name" label="Name (default error message)" type="text" errorMessage="Invalid name" validate={{
                        required: {value: true},
                        pattern: {value: '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'},
                        minLength: {value: 6},
                        maxLength: {value: 16}
                    }} />
```

It'll display the red outline and danger mark if the pattern doesn't match, which is great, but I'd also ideally like it to show the green outline and check mark when the pattern does match. Is that actually an option?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is this is the one which you want?? https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-av-reactstrap-form-9gwet

Comment: Well that does achieve the result, mostly, but no I’m more interested if there’s a “proper” way to do it (as in, built in feature of reactstrap or availity).  For example if you scroll down to Form Validation here:  https://reactstrap.github.io/components/form/.
I’ve been able to achieve it with a function and basically passing that styling to the item if it passes validation, but that’s a bit of work and I was fairly sure there’s a simple built in way to do it with reactstrap